# I want to stop the YouTube video that is played when I press the Next or Previous button on BXSLIDER

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube, bxslider

I use this script code.

How can I modify my script?

```
<div class="video-slider">              
  <div>                 
    <iframe width="100%" height="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-xmdWsgmeXk?playsinline=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>            
  </div>
  <div>                 
    <iframe width="100%" height="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-xmdWsgmeXk?playsinline=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>            
  </div>
  <div>                 
    <iframe width="100%" height="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-xmdWsgmeXk?playsinline=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>            
  </div>    
</div>
```

```
<script>
var slider = $(".video-slider").bxSlider({
            pager : false
            onSlideBefore : function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
                var src = $slideElement.find("iframe").attr("src");
                console.log(src);               
                $("iframe").attr("src",'').attr("src",src);
            }
        });
</script>
```

The video address is for samples. Let me know if there is a good way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you not write proper javascript for bxslider check my code.

```
<script>
var slider = $(".video-slider").bxSlider({
            pager : false,
            onSlideBefore : function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
                var src = $slideElement.find("iframe").attr("src");
                console.log(src);               
                $("iframe").attr("src",'').attr("src",src);
            }
        });
</script>
```